# getaguge vscode plugin with a java gauge project

Tags: getgauge

Does the VSCode plugin of getgauge work when the gauge project is a java project? I have just installed it and it seems to do nothing, I am not getting any suggestions in the specs files of my java project

Comment: Presently, gauge-vscode works only with js/python/dotnet/ruby. There's an open issue for java support https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-vscode/issues/83

Comment: too bad! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Gauge have mainly 3 types of plugins.

1. Language runners
2. IDE plugins
3. Reporter plugins

Under IDE plugins, if you are using Java, its recommended to use IntelliJ IDE. VS Code  Gauge plugin doesn't seem to work with Java projects yet.

Therefore I use IntelliJ IDE for Gauge- Java projects. And VSCode plugin for python, js and .Netcore.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions Gauge VS Code plugin (0.0.8+) and Gauge Java (0.7.1+) now supports Java on VS Code.